# How to load and draw this *.obj correctly?

Tags: opengl, textures, objects, jogl

I have a loader class for `*.obj` files (called `GLModel`) which has 2 main methods  -

```
public GLModel(BufferedReader ref, boolean centerit, GL gl,Texture texture)
```

which use for `*.obj` load  , and

```
public void opengldraw(GL gl)
```

which use for draw it on the `gl` .

so far I succeed to load and draw objects which has single `*.obj` and a texture (such `*.png` , `*jpg` etc) .

But how could I draw an object which has multiple textures ?

For example  - [this](http://www.sharecg.com/v/67490/browse/5/3D-Model/Zero) object contains multiple texture , I tried to draw it with the suitable `*.obj` and one of the texture and  got the same shape as the above link but its texture not exactly the same .

Can you supply me an example how to works it correctly ?

**Edit:**

I made that model available for download from [here](http://goo.gl/rADScE) with no register .

The drawing I got so far is  -

(front) -

[image]

(back) -

[image]

The loader class I talk about is   -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture;

// This class reads Wavefront .obj files
public class GLModel {

    private ArrayList<float[]> vertexsets;
    private ArrayList<float[]> vertexsetsnorms;
    private ArrayList<float[]> vertexsetstexs;
    private ArrayList<int[]> faces;
    private ArrayList<int[]> facestexs;
    private ArrayList<int[]> facesnorms;
    private int objectlist;
    private int numpolys;
    public float toppoint;
    public float bottompoint;
    public float leftpoint;
    public float rightpoint;
    public float farpoint;
    public float nearpoint;
    Texture texture;

    public GLModel(BufferedReader ref, boolean centerit, GL gl, 
            Texture texture){

        this.texture=texture;
        vertexsets = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        vertexsetsnorms = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        vertexsetstexs = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        faces = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        facestexs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        facesnorms = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        numpolys = 0;
        toppoint = 0.0F;
        bottompoint = 0.0F;
        leftpoint = 0.0F;
        rightpoint = 0.0F;
        farpoint = 0.0F;
        nearpoint = 0.0F;
        loadobject(ref);
        if(centerit)
            centerit();
        opengldrawtolist(gl);
        numpolys = faces.size();
        cleanup();
    }

    public GLModel(BufferedReader ref, boolean centerit, GL gl){

        vertexsets = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        vertexsetsnorms = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        vertexsetstexs = new ArrayList<float[]>();
        faces = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        facestexs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        facesnorms = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        numpolys = 0;
        toppoint = 0.0F;
        bottompoint = 0.0F;
        leftpoint = 0.0F;
        rightpoint = 0.0F;
        farpoint = 0.0F;
        nearpoint = 0.0F;
        loadobject(ref);
        if(centerit)
            centerit();
        numpolys = faces.size();
        cleanup();
    }

    private void cleanup(){
        vertexsets.clear();
        vertexsetsnorms.clear();
        vertexsetstexs.clear();
        faces.clear();
        facestexs.clear();
        facesnorms.clear();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void loadobject(BufferedReader br){
        int linecounter = 0;
        int facecounter = 0;
        try{
            boolean firstpass = true;
            String newline;
            while((newline = br.readLine()) != null){
                linecounter++;
                if(newline.length() > 0){
                    newline = newline.trim();

                    //LOADS VERTEX COORDINATES
                    if(newline.startsWith("v ")){
                        float coords[] = new float[4];
                        newline = newline.substring(2, newline.length());
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(newline, " ");
                        for(int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
                            coords[i] = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());

                        if(firstpass){
                            rightpoint = coords[0];
                            leftpoint = coords[0];
                            toppoint = coords[1];
                            bottompoint = coords[1];
                            nearpoint = coords[2];
                            farpoint = coords[2];
                            firstpass = false;
                        }
                        if(coords[0] > rightpoint)
                            rightpoint = coords[0];
                        if(coords[0] < leftpoint)
                            leftpoint = coords[0];
                        if(coords[1] > toppoint)
                            toppoint = coords[1];
                        if(coords[1] < bottompoint)
                            bottompoint = coords[1];
                        if(coords[2] > nearpoint)
                            nearpoint = coords[2];
                        if(coords[2] < farpoint)
                            farpoint = coords[2];
                        vertexsets.add(coords);
                    }
                    else

                    //LOADS VERTEX TEXTURE COORDINATES
                    if(newline.startsWith("vt")){
                        float coords[] = new float[4];
                        newline = newline.substring(3, newline.length());
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(newline, " ");
                        for(int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
                            coords[i] = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());

                        vertexsetstexs.add(coords);
                    }
                    else

                    //LOADS VERTEX NORMALS COORDINATES
                    if(newline.startsWith("vn")){
                        float coords[] = new float[4];
                        newline = newline.substring(3, newline.length());
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(newline, " ");
                        for(int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
                            coords[i] = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());

                        vertexsetsnorms.add(coords);
                    }
                    else

                    //LOADS FACES COORDINATES
                    if(newline.startsWith("f ")){
                        facecounter++;
                        newline = newline.substring(2, newline.length());
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(newline, " ");
                        int count = st.countTokens();
                        int v[] = new int[count];
                        int vt[] = new int[count];
                        int vn[] = new int[count];
                        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                            char chars[] = st.nextToken().toCharArray();
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                            char lc = 'x';
                            for(int k = 0; k < chars.length; k++){
                                if(chars[k] == '/' && lc == '/')
                                    sb.append('0');
                                lc = chars[k];
                                sb.append(lc);
                            }

                            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer
                            (sb.toString(), "/");
                            int num = st2.countTokens();
                            v[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
                            if(num > 1)
                                vt[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
                            else
                                vt[i] = 0;
                            if(num > 2)
                                vn[i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
                            else
                                vn[i] = 0;
                        }

                        faces.add(v);
                        facestexs.add(vt);
                        facesnorms.add(vn);
                    }
                    else
                        //LOADS MATERIALS
                        if (newline.charAt(0) == 'm' && newline.charAt(1) == 't' && newline.charAt(2) == 'l' && newline.charAt(3) == 'l' && newline.charAt(4) == 'i' && newline.charAt(5) == 'b') {}
                        else
                            //USES MATERIALS
                            if (newline.charAt(0) == 'u' && newline.charAt(1) == 's' && newline.charAt(2) == 'e' && newline.charAt(3) == 'm' && newline.charAt(4) == 't' && newline.charAt(5) == 'l') {}
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Failed to read file: " + br.toString());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Malformed OBJ file: " + br.toString() + "\r \r"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void centerit(){
        float xshift = (rightpoint - leftpoint) / 2.0F;
        float yshift = (toppoint - bottompoint) / 2.0F;
        float zshift = (nearpoint - farpoint) / 2.0F;
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexsets.size(); i++){
            float coords[] = new float[4];
            coords[0] = ((float[])vertexsets.get(i))[0] - leftpoint - xshift;
            coords[1] = ((float[])vertexsets.get(i))[1] - bottompoint - yshift;
            coords[2] = ((float[])vertexsets.get(i))[2] - farpoint - zshift;
            vertexsets.set(i, coords);
        }
    }

    public float getXWidth(){
        float returnval = 0.0F;
        returnval = rightpoint - leftpoint;
        return returnval;
    }

    public float getYHeight(){
        float returnval = 0.0F;
        returnval = toppoint - bottompoint;
        return returnval;
    }

    public float getZDepth(){
        float returnval = 0.0F;
        returnval = nearpoint - farpoint;
        return returnval;
    }

    public int numpolygons(){
        return numpolys;
    }

    public void opengldrawtolist(GL gl){
        // retrieving object list
        this.objectlist = gl.glGenLists(1);

        gl.glNewList(objectlist, GL.GL_COMPILE);
        texture.enable();
        texture.bind();
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);

        for (int i=0;i<faces.size();i++) {

            int[] tempfaces = (int[])(faces.get(i));
            int[] tempfacesnorms = (int[])(facesnorms.get(i));
            int[] tempfacestexs = (int[])(facestexs.get(i));

            //// Quad Begin Header ////
            int polytype;
            if (tempfaces.length == 3) {
                    polytype = GL.GL_TRIANGLES;
            } else if (tempfaces.length == 4) {
                    polytype = GL.GL_QUADS;
            } else {
                    polytype = GL.GL_POLYGON;
            }
            gl.glBegin(polytype);

            for (int w=0;w<tempfaces.length;w++) {
                if (tempfacesnorms[w] != 0) {
                    float normtempx = ((float[])vertexsetsnorms.get(tempfacesnorms[w] - 1))[0];
                    float normtempy = ((float[])vertexsetsnorms.get(tempfacesnorms[w] - 1))[1];
                    float normtempz = ((float[])vertexsetsnorms.get(tempfacesnorms[w] - 1))[2];
                    gl.glNormal3f(normtempx, normtempy, normtempz);
                }

                if (tempfacestexs[w] != 0) {
                    float textempx = ((float[])vertexsetstexs.get(tempfacestexs[w] - 1))[0];
                    float textempy = ((float[])vertexsetstexs.get(tempfacestexs[w] - 1))[1];
                    float textempz = ((float[])vertexsetstexs.get(tempfacestexs[w] - 1))[2];
                    gl.glTexCoord3f(textempx,1f-textempy,textempz);
                }

                float tempx = ((float[])vertexsets.get(tempfaces[w] - 1))[0];
                float tempy = ((float[])vertexsets.get(tempfaces[w] - 1))[1];
                float tempz = ((float[])vertexsets.get(tempfaces[w] - 1))[2];
                gl.glVertex3f(tempx,tempy,tempz);
            }
            // Quad End

            gl.glEnd();
        }

        gl.glEndList();
    }

    public void opengldraw(GL gl) {
        gl.glCallList(objectlist);
    }

    public boolean collision(float[] position) {
            return false;
    }

    public void setTexature(Texture tex) {
            this.texture = tex;
    }
}
```

The `*.obj` I used it is -  `Zero.obj` (after convert it to `BufferedReader`) , the image I used it is - `AssassinBody_Dif.jpg` (after convert it to `Texture`) .

**What I looking for is  - how to get completely drawing of  that model using the attached `GLModel` class ?**

Comment: can you show us what your rendering looks like ?

Comment: sure , look at the edited post please .

Comment: That is indeed looking weird. At first I thought you had wrong texture coordinates, but then again it looks a bit like the render on the site from front, so texture coordinates might be correct. I actually have no idea about this one.

Comment: But yes there are normal maps and specular maps in addition to diffuse maps in the zip file, as I guessed.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. The head, chest and some other parts are separate, and they all have different textures. Just like I thought in my answer's first paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wavefront obj files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) usually are combined with material files (.mat) which define the textures used. The meshes of a model are divided in different material groups. Each material tells you which textures to use and other information of the mesh.

In your case, there are separate meshes on the model. These meshes are head, body and hands. They all have their own textures, which you will need to apply to the correct meshes for it to look right. The meshes are most likely separated in the .obj file in mesh groups, material groups or lighting groups. You need to read them in separate mesh instances to be able to render them with different textures.

You also have encountered something called [normal mapping](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Lighting_of_Bumpy_Surfaces), which is in essence saving some of the high-poly model's mesh data in textures for use with low-poly model.

Comment: can you elaborate how he might have encountered normal mapping? objs and their material files do not define normal maps nor multi-texture or multi-tex coordinates.

Comment: @concept3d I am just looking at the final render of the model on the site he linked, and that looks like it's been normal mapped and specular highlighted. And it is not unheard of to .obj materials to have normal maps and specular maps. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vendor_specific_alterations

Comment: I just checked it, well it might be. Even though I doubt obj stores bump maps info, the image might not represent the real model.

Comment: Also, the site suggests that the .obj file is not the original file, but just a version of it. It says on the page this: Format: OBJ (.obj), Poser (.pz3, .pp2)

Comment: well yes I suspected that.

Comment: @Lasse : I put the model available for download  , maybe it gives you more information .

Comment: just as a note mutlitexturing is different from having multiple textures. So you at least posted the wrong link

Comment: I edited the answer.